# QPrintPreviewDialog hangs if screen resolution is 2560x1600

Tags: qt, screen-resolution, print-preview

I have a problem with **QPrintPreviewDialog** - when my report has 2 pages and screen resolution is 2560x1600 it hangs - application starts to "eat" the memory.
I do not have such a problem when screen resolution is 1920x1200 or less, or my report has 1, 3 or more pages. ( :-\ )
Even when I have a problem with previewing (2560x1600, 2 pages), my report prints normaly, no matter I select to print all the pages or a range.

After installation event filter on QPrintPreviewDialog (event types):

```
QPainter::end() returned: true
PrintPreviewDialog: 203
PrintPreviewDialog: 13
PrintPreviewDialog: 14
PrintPreviewDialog: 152
PrintPreviewDialog: 17
PrintPreviewDialog: 13
PrintPreviewDialog: 24
PrintPreviewDialog: 99
PrintPreviewDialog: 26
PrintPreviewDialog: 76
PrintPreviewDialog: 77
PrintPreviewDialog: 12
PrintPreviewDialog: 76
PrintPreviewDialog: 77
PrintPreviewDialog: 12
PrintPreviewDialog: 76
PrintPreviewDialog: 76
PrintPreviewDialog: 77
PrintPreviewDialog: 12
PrintPreviewDialog: 173
PrintPreviewDialog: 76
PrintPreviewDialog: 25    !!!
PrintPreviewDialog: 99
```

I found out that when the problem occurs QEvent::WindowDeactivate is present ...
Qt version - 4.8.1, Windows 7 Pro x64.
How to find out what is going on?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If app hang it probably means some infinitive loop. Run it in debug mode reach situation when app hangs then press pause button in debugger and inspect call stack of each thread (repeat this couple times). This should help you spot place in code where your app is hanging. Add results to this question.

Comment: thanks for your help, @Marek R,
it is not easy to do - I do not have such a monitor at my working position :)

Comment: Is it relay screen resolution dependent? Strange. Anyway you can connect second monitor and configure windows to threat those two monitors as one big one.

Comment: Somehow **it really depends on screen resolution** - when I set screen resolution to 1920x1200 everything is OK. It also runs without any problem when report contains 1, 3 or more pages, even if screen resolution is 2560x1600

Comment: Most likely it doesn't depend on resolution but on dialog size. Are you sure that when the dialog is forcibly resized to be small prior to showing it, you still have the issue? This is likely a Qt bug. To reproduce it, you shouldn't depend on screen resolution at all. Simply create a sufficiently large window that extends past the screen boundary - this will hopefully reproduce the issue. When posting your bug, include a small, single-file reproducible test case. It should be probably a couple lines long at most. Just fire up the dialog, resize it, and draw something  on the pseudo-printer.

Comment: I am not sure I got you right, @Kuba. What should I do to reproduce this issue - create QMainWindow, create QDialog and show it, then resize dialog (or main window is to be resized?) and then "draw something on pseudo-printer". Do I understand you correctly? What do you mean - "pseudo-printer"?